# Execute Jupyter Notebook / Colab instruction in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, google-colaboratory

I cannot integrate this code 1 to 1 in PyCharm because the instructions such as `!mkdir ~/.kaggle` are not recognized.
How can I rebuild this source code so that it also works in Pycharm? Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import json
import zipfile
import glob

username_kaggle = "dummy"
token_kaggle = "token"
savepath = "/content/dataset/retailrocket"

if not os.path.exists(savepath):
    os.makedirs(savepath)
os.chdir(savepath)

# Download the dataset from kaggle
!pip install kaggle

!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!touch ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

api_token = {"username":username_kaggle,"key":token_kaggle}
with open('/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)
!kaggle datasets download -d retailrocket/ecommerce-dataset
```

Comment: Its not recognized because the exclamation mark commands are not normally python code. These only work in Ipython. Anything with the exclamation mark is supposed to run in the system console instead of in python itself.

Comment: @FrozenAra Thank you very much for the comment. Is there any other option so that I can write this right into the code? Because I don't want to use the terminal every time.

Comment: You dont need to run most of the codes again. The pip command for example just installs the kaggle python package. You only need to do that once.
The other commands are filea handling commands so you probably only need to run them once as well.
I do not have knowledge of kaggle so I cant help you there.

Comment: Thank you! The pip install, which I can do via terminal. Unfortunately, changing the folder and so on does not work. Since the token has to be stored as a JSON file in Users / .kaggle.

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: I'm using windows. https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api Here is the documentation from Kaggle, this token only needs to be stored in a certain folder structure and called from there

Comment: Yeah thats why its not working. `touch` is a unix command and `mkdir` wont work like that on windows

Comment: Ok, is there a possibility that I can save the token in a certain structure?

Comment: I am writing an answer right now!

Comment: @FrozenAra thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to write a real answer instead of a comment here.

```
!pip install kaggle
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!touch ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download -d retailrocket/ecommerce-datase
```

These parts of the code won't work because the exclamation mark commans isnot normally python code. These only work in Ipython. Anything with the exclamation mark is supposed to run in the system console instead of in python itself.

As you noted in your comments you are using windows. So most of these commands wont work.

```
pip install kaggle
```

This command will work normally in in the windows shell as long as pip is installed.

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
```

This command creates a new folder and should look like the following in windows (It depends on where you want to save that json file):

```
mkdir "C:\kaggle"
```

Modifiy this path to where you need the file.

```
touch
```

Touch creates and empty file in a specific folder.
On windows this command can be run like this:

```
type nul > "C:\kaggle\kaggle.json"
```

Here you again need to use the path you used with the mkdir command up top.

I dont know what `kaggle datasets download -d retailrocket/ecommerce-dataset` exactly does but it seems its dowloading some dataset from kaggle.
I imagine you can run this command once in your console and forget about afterwards.